# Throwing multiple exceptions inside of a function

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling, throw

I'm implementing a form validation function that throws Errors. These exceptions will bubble up and be managed on a higher level inside my application:

```
this.form.inputs.forEach(input => {
  if (input.required && !input.value) {
    throw new AppError({ customMessage: new Notification(notificationTypes.Error, `${input.label} not filled`)});
  }
})
```

The thing is throwing an exception stops the function execution, so I can only catch the first error.

Any suggestion? I am running out of ideas : (

Comment: Instead of throwing immediately just collect all the exceptions and only after the function ends throw a collection of them?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue checking, you need to not throw an exception. Instead, have an array of objects indicating the problem, and throw a single exception with that array:

```
const errors = [];
this.form.inputs.forEach(input => {
    if (input.required && !input.value) {
        errors.push({ customMessage: new Notification(notificationTypes.Error, `${input.label} not filled`)});
    }
});
if (errors.length) {
    throw new AppError(errors);
}
```

Comment: I see. So throwing an exception stops the execution of a function; exactly as a return does. I've been searching for a while and I haven't found any reference to that behavior yet, but is good to know it. Thanks!

Comment: @SergioMartín - Yup, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
const errs = this.form.inputs
  .map(input => {
    if (input.required && !input.value) {
      return new AppError({ customMessage: new Notification(notificationTypes.Error, `${input.label} not filled`)});
    }
  })
  .filter(err => err !== undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an exception is thrown the execution inside that thread is aborted and flux control goes to the calling thread.

IF you want to return validation messages for all controls, you can add them to an array inside your for loop and then return those values (or throw an exception outside the for loop).

Answer (score 0):

this could solve your problem

```
this.form.inputs.forEach(input => {
 try {
  if (input.required && !input.value) {
    throw new AppError({ customMessage: new Notification(notificationTypes.Error, `${input.label} not filled`)});
  }
 }
catch (e) {
     console.log(e)
} 
})
```

please try this and comment back

Comment: It enters in the catch on each throw. Because the exceptions gets caught it doesn't bubble up, so my error handler will never receive it. Thanks for trying it tho!